# How to find Lagest sum consecutive increasing digits in a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can i find the Largest sum consecutive increasing digits and its position in a Number using python ?

Here is my approach :

def findLIS(A, n):
hash = dict()

```
LIS_size, LIS_index = 1, 0
  
hash[A[0]] = 1
  
for i in range(1, n): 
    if A[i] - 1 not in hash: 
        hash[A[i] - 1] = 0



    hash[A[i]] = hash[A[i] - 1] + 1
    if LIS_size < hash[A[i]]: 
        LIS_size = hash[A[i]] 
        LIS_index = A[i] 
start = LIS_index - LIS_size + 1
while start <= LIS_index: 
    # print(start, end = " ") 
    z.insert(i - 1,start)
    
 

       start += 1
    print(z[~0])
    print(sum(z))
# Driver Code 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    num = input()
    A = [int(x) for x in str(num)]
    
    n = len(A) 
    z=[]
    findLIS(A, n)
```

Comment: Can you say in words how you would do this? What do you need to look at? What do you need to keep track of. Don't think about the programming language just the logic of what you need to do. This should help you identify the things to do in python. (For example iterate through the digits in the number.) You can then ask for help with the bits you don't know how to do.

Comment: why answer in second example is 3:3-4, not 4:1-1?

Comment: @AliaksandrPlekhau sorry yes i that case answer will be 4

Comment: @djna hey man check my edit , i posted my approach but the issue is i dont know how i'll print the position.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
n = input()+"0"

max_sum = 0
max_pos = ""
start = 0
sum = int(n[0])
for i in range(1, len(n)):
    if n[i-1] >= n[i]:
        if max_sum < sum:
            max_sum = sum
            max_pos = "{}-{}".format(start+1, i)
        start = i
        sum = int(n[i])
    else:
        sum += int(n[i])
print("{}:{}".format(max_sum, max_pos))
```

There is numbers should strictly increase. If sequence `333` also match your condition that you need to change condition: `if n[i-1] > n[i]:`